# If something is oversold, is it worth more or less than the sell price?

Tags: definition

On one hand, in the context of stock market, Lexico dictionary defines the word "oversold" as follows:

> Sold at a price below its true value.

On the other hand, when defining the word "oversell", it says:

> Exaggerate the merits of

These meanings seem contradicting to me: the first one defines "oversold" as something whose price is less than its true value, while the second one defines "oversold" as something whose (concieved) price is more than its true value.

Do I get it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One meaning is the past tense of oversell - which you surmise correctly.

> I oversold the performance of my car

Meaning you inflated it's actual performance value by talking it up.

However there is a second meaning of the word oversold in relation to stock markets, and that is to be sold so that the value falls below actual value.

> financial markets, shares, etc. where prices have fallen too far in relation to their real value [Cambs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oversold)
>
> Of a stock market, etc.: that has fallen too quickly as a result of excessive selling; (also) characteristic of such a market. [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/258996?)

In this situation oversold means the stock has been sold too much, making the stock market value below their actual value.

Comment: I see, so on both cases, *oversold* means that something has been sold too much. Thanks.